# Unity ViewtoWorldPoint not working, what did I do wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, 2d

I am trying to follow along this tutorial and make a Space Invaders replica, but I am probably going to tweak it later on to be more geometry wars style.

Any way I am teaching myself C# and Unity at the same time so it is rather difficult, I understand most of the code but some of it I do not, and that is where the hang up is I believe...

The code is supposed to move my formations Left and Right across the screen, but after hours of trying to edit my code and tweak it the only thing I have noticed is when I change the **BoundaryLeftEdge** and **BoundaryRightEdge** Vector 3's there is different behavior... but it still either moves to the left and moves back and fourth like it should except it is like offset from the screen or it moves to the right and gets stuck so on and so fourth... I want it to move back and fourth from point A to point B but I cannot seem to manage that :( Sorry I'm such a noob in need, Self teaching is more difficult than I figured I guess

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FormationController : MonoBehaviour
{   //Spawning Variables
    public GameObject EnemyPrefab;
    public float W = 10, H = 5;
    //Movement Variables
    public float Speed = 5;
    private int Direction;
    private float BoundaryRightEdge, BoundaryLeftEdge;
    public float Padding = 0.25f;


void Start() //Setting Boundary
{
    Camera camera = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
    float distance = camera.transform.position.z - camera.transform.position.z;
    BoundaryLeftEdge = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distance)).x + Padding;
    BoundaryRightEdge = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, distance)).x - Padding;
}

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    float xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
    xmin = transform.position.x - 0.5f * W;
    xmax = transform.position.x + 0.5f * W;
    ymin = transform.position.y - 0.5f * H;
    ymax = transform.position.y + 0.5f * H;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector3(xmin, ymin, 0), new Vector3(xmin, ymax));
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector3(xmin, ymax, 0), new Vector3(xmax, ymax));
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector3(xmax, ymax, 0), new Vector3(xmax, ymin));
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector3(xmax, ymin, 0), new Vector3(xmin, ymin));

}

void Update()
{
    float formationRightEdge = transform.position.x + 0.5f * W;
    float formationLeftEdge = transform.position.x - 0.5f * W;
    if (formationRightEdge > BoundaryRightEdge)
    {
        Direction = -1;
    }
    if (formationLeftEdge < BoundaryLeftEdge)
    {
        Direction = 1;
    }
    transform.position += new Vector3(Direction * Speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

    //Spawn Enemies on Keypress
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            GameObject enemy = Instantiate(EnemyPrefab, child.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            enemy.transform.parent = child;
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 1):

According to your codes, I can only assume that `formationRightEdge` should be less than `BoundaryLeftEdge` and `formationLeftEdge` should be greater than `BoundaryLeftEdge` unless you are doing transformation in reverse direction in world point.

Try this -

```
if (formationRightEdge < BoundaryRightEdge)
{
    Direction = -1;
}
if (formationLeftEdge > BoundaryLeftEdge)
{
    Direction = 1;
}
```

Maybe your `Direction = 1` and `Direction = -1` should be reversed. And of course, check whether you set the values for your public variables in the inspector differently. You can reset to the default values there (defined in this script).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I have been trying to solve this problem all damn day.... I even found the original game project from the tutorial and loaded it and come to find out it was made with unity 4.6 and I am using 5, but I just realized if I move my player sprite (With the camera attached to it) Outside of the formation gizmo then my script works just fine, but if I move my player into the center of the formation (0,0,0) in unity then the script just does absolutely nothing.... Could this be another unity 5 bug? It did not ask me to convert any code when I opened the tutorial project

Comment: I don't know then what's happening! I don't think it's a unity bug rather project setup. You can try on a 4.6 version to see what comes up. Good luck.